# SQL Query to show string before a dash

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to execute a query that will only show all the string before dash in the particular field.

**For example:**

Original data: `AB-123`

After query: `AB`

Comment: sql query is only needed for the above query, plsql is only needed if the logic cannot be done using sql, or if using loops or condition etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions181.htm#i87066):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (SELECT 'AB-123' txt FROM dual)
  2  SELECT substr(txt, 1, instr(txt, '-') - 1)
  3    FROM DATA;

SUBSTR(TXT,1,INSTR(TXT,'-')-1)
------------------------------
AB
```

or [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) (10g+):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (SELECT 'AB-123' txt FROM dual)
  2  SELECT regexp_substr(txt, '^[^-]*')
  3    FROM DATA;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(TXT,'^[^-]*')
---------------------------
AB
```

Comment: The first variant will return an empty string for input strings that don't contain a dash (not sure whether the OP wants this, though).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt What's not specified can only be unexpected =)

Comment: '[^-]+' seems a shorter alternative for your second argument to the regexp_substr function. Or am I missing some edge case?

Comment: @RobvanWijk I would say that you'd need either the first `^` or the last `*` (instead of `+`) to make sure that a value starting with a `-` returns null. I would consider this an edge case anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple

```
 SELECT distinct
        regexp_replace(d.pyid, '-.*$', '') as result
    FROM schema.table d;
```

pyID column contains ABC-123, DEF-3454

SQL Result:

ABC
DEF

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).

For example

```
    WITH DATA AS (
         SELECT 'AB-123' as text FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ABC123' as text FROM dual
    )
    SELECT 
        regexp_replace(d.text, '-.*$', '') as result
    FROM DATA d;
```

will lead to

```
    WITH DATA AS (
      2      SELECT 'AB-123' as text FROM dual
      3      UNION ALL
      4      SELECT 'ABC123' as text FROM dual
      5  )
      6  SELECT
      7     regexp_replace(d.text, '-.*$', '') as result
      8  FROM DATA d;

    RESULT
    ------------------------------------------------------
    AB
    ABC123
```